# wget unable to resolve host address

Tags: wget

```
wget http:www.google.be
resolving http (http)...failed:Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'http'
```

Question:
What can be the issue/solution?

Comment: Try the proper syntax `wget http://www.google.be`

Comment: probably would work without the http (or slashes_

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the syntax in your command is incorrect.
Your command was:
`wget http:www.google.be`

The correct command should look something like this:
`wget https://www.google.be`

You did not add slashes after "http:" which made wget believe that HTTP is an address on its own. (instead of using it as the protocol.)